# Downloading file from imgur using python directly via url

Tags: python, bash, imgur

Sometime, links to imgur are not given with the file extension. For example: `http://imgur.com/rqCqA`. I want to download the file and give it a known name or get it name inside a larger code. The problem is that I don't know the file type, so I don't know what extension to give it.

How can I achieve this in python or bash?

Comment: Isn't the mimetype going to be text/html because the link is a page, not an image? I don't think this would work.

Comment: It is actually ``(none, none)``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried going to the following URLs:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7t3N.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ruBm.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUNjJ.jpg

And they all worked. It seems that Imgur stores several types of the same image - you can take your pick.

Comment: It actually only stores the JPEG, and relies on the browser (correctly) ignoring the file extension and using the mime type. 

You should use i.imgur.com instead of imgur.com for the image - while it works, it's not guaranteed to continue working as they never give out those links.

Answer (score 7):

You should use the [Imgur JSON API](http://api.imgur.com/resources_anon#image_hash). Here's an example in Python, using [requests](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/):

```
import posixpath
import urllib.parse
import requests

url = "http://api.imgur.com/2/image/rqCqA.json"
r = requests.get(url)
img_url = r.json["image"]["links"]["original"]
fn = posixpath.basename(urllib.parse.urlsplit(img_url).path)

r = requests.get(img_url)
with open(fn, "wb") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: use `r.json` instead of `json.loads(r.content.decode('utf-8'))`. also `posixpath.basename(urlparse.urlsplit(img_url).path)`

Comment: You're right; I just copy-pasted some code I had for a much older version of requests. And thanks for the `urlsplit` tip.

Comment: @Schnouki I get this error : {"data":{"error":"The version of the Imgur API you are using is no longer available"},"success":false,"status":410}

Answer (score 3):

I've used this before to download tons of xkcd webcomics and it seems to work for [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7t3N.jpg) as well.

```
def saveImage(url, fpath):
    contents = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    f = open(fpath, 'w')
    f.write(contents.read())
    f.close()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: does using `wb` instead of `w` makes any difference here? Though the output comes out be same.

Comment: Haven't tried it with `wb`, but I can't imagine it hurting the process

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the source of the page using BeautifulSoup or similar and look for img tags with the photo hash in the src. With your example, the pic is

```
<img alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/rqCqA.jpg" original-title="">
```